# How to parse a form of csv file in java

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I am trying to parse a rather special-formatted file by using scanner with delimiter, but I am rather new to regex. The format:

"MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH","JENNIFER",...

Currently, I am using this delimiter and code below:

```
static void readNames(String[] names) {

    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("names.txt")).useDelimiter(",");
        int count = 0;

        while(sc.hasNext()) {

            names[count] = sc.next();
            count ++;


        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

However, this gives me quotes around the String which is not what I want.

Then, I tried to the following delimiter:

```
String delimiter = " "," ";
```

Which I quickly realised is not recognised as a String due to the amount of quotation marks.

This is edited after I got my answer, but is there any way to do it the way I intended in the second delimiter, by using the "," as the delimiter?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Please make an [attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at writing some [code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). If you get stuck please do some [research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) and provide details of what you found and why it does not solve your problem. See the [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for more details.

Comment: I appreciate you giving me info on how to pose a question in the future. Much appreciated!

Comment: Not in the future. If you are serious about asking real questions you should improve this one. Otherwise you will only attract down and close votes, which is a bad way to start here. If you think you can't improve this question, honestly, then consider deleting it.

Comment: Sorry again, new to StackOverflow.  @GhostCat, I have edited the question according to your suggestions. Consider taking another look at it, thanks!

Comment: @VetleHjelmtvedt: You need to escape the doublequotes within a string. But even if you do so, this won't work because normally "," could have been the delimiter but you have doublequote at the start and end of file/line, so you need to use Pattern regex like I wrote in my answer. You can run my code as is and see what it outputs and then I can refine my answer once you provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the data given in your post, I think you can use this pattern ","|"

Following is the kind of code you can write,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("filename.txt"));
    sc.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("\",\"|\""));

    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(sc.next());
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a java written helpful csv parser. I wrote a pretty nice one recently:

```
public static Iterable<String[]> parseCSV(final InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    return new Iterable<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<String[]> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<String[]>() {
                static final int UNCALCULATED = 0;
                static final int READY = 1;
                static final int FINISHED = 2;
                int state = UNCALCULATED;
                ArrayList<String> value_list = new ArrayList<>();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String[] return_value;

                public void end() {
                    end_part();
                    return_value = new String[value_list.size()];
                    value_list.toArray(return_value);
                    value_list.clear();
                }

                public void end_part() {
                    value_list.add(sb.toString());
                    sb.setLength(0);
                }

                public void append(int ch) {
                    sb.append((char) ch);
                }

                public void calculate() throws IOException {
                    boolean inquote = false;
                    while (true) {
                        int ch = stream.read();
                        switch (ch) {
                            default: //regular character.
                                append(ch);
                                break;
                            case -1: //read has reached the end.
                                if ((sb.length() == 0) && (value_list.isEmpty())) {
                                    state = FINISHED;
                                } else {
                                    end();
                                    state = READY;
                                }
                                return;
                            case '\r':
                            case '\n': //end of line.
                                if (inquote) {
                                    append(ch);
                                } else {
                                    end();
                                    state = READY;
                                    return;
                                }
                                break;
                            case ',': //comma
                                if (inquote) {
                                    append(ch);
                                } else {
                                    end_part();
                                    break;
                                }
                                break;
                            case '"': //quote.
                                inquote = !inquote;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    if (state == UNCALCULATED) {
                        try {
                            calculate();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                        }
                    }
                    return state == READY;
                }

                @Override
                public String[] next() {
                    if (state == UNCALCULATED) {
                        try {
                            calculate();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                        }
                    }
                    state = UNCALCULATED;
                    return return_value;
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

You would typically process this quite helpfully like:

```
for (String[] csv : parseCSV(stream)) {
    //<deal with parsed csv data>
}
```

Generally it wraps a csv stream parser in an iterable so you can use the special java for loops. So you feed it a stream and it'll give you a for loop of arrays of strings, which is typically going to be the best way you'd want that data.

If you rather want understanding, you'll need to better phrase your question with additional information that makes it clear what you think you need and why, because most of your post doesn't make much sense.